# Row deletion operation on pg table with numerous foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, maintenance

I maintain a Django app with a postgresql backend. Users log in and exchange messages (forum style) with one another.

All users are identified by unique `usernames` (saved in the `auth_user` table), that also double up as `nicknames` for the users when they interact with one another in the forum.

I want to delete/deprecate data of users who haven't logged a session in my web app since the past 3 months. I'm doing this in order to *free up nicknames* for new users. I.e. new users need to keep a nickname, and if one's taken, they are made to retry. So if I can get rid of old users, the average number of retries a new user has to do will go down too. I.e. it'll become easier for incoming newbies to register for my service. So that's my goal here.

Ideally, I would simply delete the required rows from `auth_user`, however there are foreign key constraints that get violated (since `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not set on them, most are `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`).

I was going to edit all these foreign key constraints and change them to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. But before I do that, I wanted to get expert advice on whether that's my only option in the scenario I've described. I'll have to make changes to foreign keys in ~50 tables, and secondly, `ON DELETE CASCADE` feels a bit too aggressive.

Comment: Just a reflection, if you remove their messages conversations they participated in might look weird.

Comment: @Lennart: True, what's an alternative strategy you would suggest?

Comment: Can't you just update the nicknames to NULL or like stackoverflow, to a sequence-driven anonymous name?

Comment: @DanielVérité: that's not a bad idea. You could elaborate that with an example and just write it as an answer too, since in my case, it's a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an SQL that does the same as the `ON DELETE CASCADE` would do. Remove the rows from the corresponding ~50 tables in the right order before you remove the users. This is some work but it keeps your data safe from an application error that does an accidental remove of a user with (lots of) messages.

Comment: 'mimics' as in?

Comment: acts like. does the same thing.

Comment: So you literally meant SQL that does it by brute force

Comment: I meant an SQL script that does the same thing as the `ON DELETE CASCADE` would do.